# Wordpress ACF Repeater Image resize

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to resize an image coming from the Advanced Custom Fields repeater field with no success.

I have set up a basic non-repeater image field in the exact same way elsewhere on the page and it works perfectly.

So I have the image size set up in the functions.php:

```
add_image_size( 'bio-size', 400, 260, true );
```

Then in the template I have:

```
<?php while( have_rows('bio') ): the_row();

  $bioImgObj = get_sub_field('bio_image');
  $bioImgSize = 'bio-size';
  $bioImgUrl = $bioImgObj['sizes'][$bioImgSize];

?>

<img width="400" height="260" src="<?php echo $bioImgUrl; ?>"/>
```

This gives me the image, but does not resize it in any way.

Comment: Did you add the imagesize before or after uploading the image?
Had similiar issues when altering ACF field configs or image sizes after content was uploaded.

Comment: Wait, that's it! I thought I tested that but I have changed the coding since then. Add this as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using ACF, or general WordPress file uploads, modifying image sizes or other configs for files **after** upload wont affect already uploaded files because the files are processed on upload.